# How to read lines that skip reading lines having Characters of "01" and "25"

Tags: substring

Example:

```
FSA claim 'TO' date of service is 20111201 and the selection date is 20110627
FSA claim 'TO' date of service is 20110702 and the selection date is 20110627
FSA claim 'TO' date of service is 20110725 and the selection date is 20110627
```

my code is:

```
else if (line.ToUpper().Contains(" FSA CLAIM 'TO' DATE"))
{
    if (!(line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "01" & (!(line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "25"))))
    {
        //MyClaimNumber = MyHoldline.Substring(25, 12);
        outputFSAClaimtodate.WriteLine(MyHoldline);
        outputFSAClaimtodate.WriteLine(line);
```

it still read those line containing them.

My target out should be like this:

```
FSA claim 'TO' date of service is 20110702 and the selection date is 20110627
```

Please help!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip reading if a particular line contains a specific day of the month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626653/how-to-skip-reading-if-a-particular-line-contains-a-specific-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
!(line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "01" & (!(line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "25")))
```

is confusing. It has, for example:

```
!(line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "25")
```

or "not (not equals)", which is the same as "equals":

```
(line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() == "25")
```

If you mean "neither X nor Y", that's "(not X) and (not Y)":

```
if (line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "01" && line.Substring(34, 2).Trim() != "25")
```

Comment: Also note the single `&` in the OP's code. Assuming this is C#, it should be `&&` like your example.

Comment: Hello guys, it still does not get the output that I want. The output should be like this "FSA claim 'TO' date of service is 20110702 and the selection date is 20110627" It stil read those string having date of "01" and date of "25". See this string "FSA claim 'TO' date of service is 20110701 and the selection date is 20110627" I don't want to write this line because it contains "01" (20110701)

Comment: Your index (34) looks to be incorrect. For all three lines, assuming a line of the input you provided is what `line` refers to, `line.Substring(34, 2)` returns `"20"`. I recommend running your code through a debugger to see what it's doing.